# Documenting an exception in C# code

Tags: c#, exception, documentation

I noticed in `mscorlib.xml` (the XML file that is generated from the summaries) that it contains:

```xml
<member name="M:System.Console.ReadKey">
  <summary>Obtains the next character or function key pressed by the user. The pressed key is displayed in the console window.</summary>
  <returns>A <see cref="T:System.ConsoleKeyInfo" /> object that describes the <see cref="T:System.ConsoleKey" /> constant and Unicode character, if any, that correspond to the pressed console key. The <see cref="T:System.ConsoleKeyInfo" /> object also describes, in a bitwise combination of <see cref="T:System.ConsoleModifiers" /> values, whether one or more SHIFT, ALT, or CTRL modifier keys was pressed simultaneously with the console key.</returns>
  <exception cref="T:System.InvalidOperationException">The <see cref="P:System.Console.In" /> property is redirected from some stream other than the console.</exception>
  <filterpriority>1</filterpriority>
</member>
```

From that example I am specifically interested in:

```xml
<exception cref="T:System.InvalidOperationException">The <see cref="P:System.Console.In" /> property is redirected from some stream other than the console.</exception>
```

How do you document exceptions in code so that they end up in the XML?

Comment: Strange question, since you already give the answer yourself :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's an example:

```
/// <exception cref="ArgumentException">
/// Thrown when the <typeparamref name="TConcrete"/> is a type
/// that can not be created by the container.
/// </exception>
```

In other words, exactly as the code snippet you already showed in your question.

Comment: I just realized that :P. Are there any tips for making it easier?

Comment: Well I suppose at least knowing that I don't have to type in the full name makes it a bit easier, so thank you for that. Is there a list of elements and attributes that can be used?

Comment: [XML Documentation Comments (C# Programming Guide)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b2s063f7%28v=VS.100%29.aspx) is a good place to start.

Comment: [Recommended Tags for Documentation Comments (C# Programming Guide)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5ast78ax.aspx) if you want just the list of XML elements.

Comment: Visual Studio will give you IntelliSense (auto complete) on the XML documentation, which is very useful.

Comment: And don't forget the very useful `<![CDATA[` ([link](http://omegacoder.com/?p=397)).

Comment: Found them all in the ECMA. Thank you for the help. I wonder if there are any visual studio plugins which make the documentation process easier.

Comment: There is a plugin that I love: [GhostDoc](http://submain.com/products/ghostdoc.aspx). It rules.

Answer (score 2):

You can add the exception documentation with the `<exception>` tag in the XML comments in your source code.  For example:

```
///<summary>Summary of method/property/etc</summary>
///<returns>Returns a value</returns>
///<exception>Throws an exception</exception>
```